# JavaScript variable not working in HTML Audio control?

Tags: javascript, html

Audio player not serving its purpose, audio source URL received in `JSON` and saved in a audio path, variable passed as `SRC` attribute, still doesn't seem to work

```
var audio_path = json_defects.audio_path;

$('#audio_edit').html('<audio controls><source src="audio_path" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the `src` to the *literal string* `"audio_path"`.  Variables don't automatically expand in strings.

Instead, concatenate the variable into the resulting string:

```
'<audio controls><source src="' + audio_path + '" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>'
```